# Order rows that replace the id

Tags: sql, sql-server, dml

Lets say I have a table with the current ID.

```
CREATE TABLE F
(
    id int,
    s char
)

INSERT INTO F VALUES(10)
```

and another table with rows that can either replace the id or update something.

```
CREATE TABLE M
(
    id int,
    old_id int,
    new_id int,
    type char,
    s char,
    d date
)
```

Where in type indicates if it replaces the id or updates s.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.M (id, old_id, new_id, type, d, s) 
VALUES
(2, 20,NULL,'U', '2018-01-01', 'a'),
(3, 10,20,  'R', '2018-01-01', NULL),
(4, 10,NULL,'U', '2018-01-01', 'b'),
(5, 20,NULL,'U', '2018-01-01', 'c'),
(6, 30,NULL,'U', '2018-01-01', 'd'),
(7, 20,30,  'R', '2018-01-01', NULL),
(8, 30,NULL,'U', '2018-01-01', 'e'),
(9, 40,NULL,'U', '2018-01-01', 'f')
```

If I want to sort the rows so that 'U' that match the id in F comes first, then 'R' that match the id, then the following rows should sort by the id that every 'R' sets.

So the order for this would be 4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8 or 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need recursion for this:

```
CREATE TABLE f(id int, s char);
INSERT INTO f(id) VALUES
(10);

CREATE TABLE m(id int, old_id int, new_id int, type char, s char, d date);
INSERT INTO m (id, old_id, new_id, type, d, s) VALUES
(2, 20, NULL, 'U', '2018-01-01', 'a'),
(3, 10, 20,   'R', '2018-01-01', NULL),
(4, 10, NULL, 'U', '2018-01-01', 'b'),
(5, 20, NULL, 'U', '2018-01-01', 'c'),
(6, 30, NULL, 'U', '2018-01-01', 'd'),
(7, 20, 30,   'R', '2018-01-01', NULL),
(8, 30, NULL, 'U', '2018-01-01', 'e'),
(9, 40, NULL, 'U', '2018-01-01', 'f');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 1 AS lvl
    FROM m AS base
    WHERE old_id = (SELECT id FROM f)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT curr.*, lvl + 1
    FROM m AS curr
    INNER JOIN cte AS prev ON prev.type = 'R' AND curr.old_id = prev.new_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY lvl, CASE type WHEN 'U' THEN 1 WHEN 'R' THEN 2 END
```

Result:

```
| id | old_id | new_id | type | s | d          | lvl |
|----|--------|--------|------|---|------------|-----|
| 4  | 10     |        | U    | b | 01/01/2018 | 1   |
| 3  | 10     | 20     | R    |   | 01/01/2018 | 1   |
| 2  | 20     |        | U    | a | 01/01/2018 | 2   |
| 5  | 20     |        | U    | c | 01/01/2018 | 2   |
| 7  | 20     | 30     | R    |   | 01/01/2018 | 2   |
| 6  | 30     |        | U    | d | 01/01/2018 | 3   |
| 8  | 30     |        | U    | e | 01/01/2018 | 3   |
```

- The *base* part of the recursive cte contains all rows containing 10
- You then proceed by selecting `R` rows from *prev* iterations to get the new id and select rows from the main table where old id = new id
- You finally sort the rows in the order they were processed in the cte